# Multiple INSERTS in a single transaction in aws redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, insert, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

I am trying to use data modifying CTE with amazon redshift

```
INSERT INTO offer_spend(offer_id)
WITH cte AS (
    INSERT INTO offer
    (offer_id, offer_name, offer_type, offer_desc)
  VALUES
    (1, 'abc', 'xyz', 'an offer')
  RETURNING id
)
SELECT id
FROM cte;
```

So trying to insert the id returned by the inner insert into the outer insert. But it always gives `[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "INSERT"`

I have looked up mulitple examples online struggling with the same fact. Is it possible to do it in redshift. ***I wish to do multiple inserts in a single transaction and rollback if anyone of them fails. What is the best approach to do so in Redshift***

**UPDATE**:

I tried the following:

```
BEGIN transaction;
INSERT INTO offer
    (offer_id, offer_name, offer_type, offer_desc)
VALUES (1, 'abc', 'xyz', 'an offer');
INSERT INTO offer_spend
    (offer_id, amount)
VALUES (1, 4000);
COMMIT transaction;
```

But now I get the error `Cannot use commit while Connection is in auto-commit mode`

Comment: I don't think Redshift supports `update`/`delete`/`insert` in a CTE.  Only `select`:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WITH_clause.html.

Comment: is there another syntax I could use. I am sure this is a very common use-case

Comment: . . Use multiple statements with transactions.  That is how you do multiple data modifying steps in most databases.

Comment: I am familiar with transactions but dont know how to provide the returning id of one into another insert as is the case here. Could you provide an example

Comment: Can I ask what you are trying to achieve? For what purpose are you saving this id?

Comment: I updated my question. I am inserting into two tables that have a foreign key constraint. I want to make inserts two both but a single transaction will have the same id

Comment: Having 2 inserts in the same transaction that are committed (or rolled back) at the same time is easy.  Getting the id of the first insert into the second (with the same transaction constraint) is the tricky part.  Why do you want the id (query #?) of the insert in the 2nd insert?  Would the session id meet your needs?

Comment: A single row insert inside a transaction consumes at least four megabytes of disk I/O *per column in the table* (I can prove four, but I suspect it might be more).  If you have say 30 columns, and 100 rows, that's 100 * 30 * 4 = 12 *gigabytes* of disk I/O.  Are you sure you want to be doing this?

Comment: My database and sql knowledge is not the best. I am working on redshift and do want those two inserts to happen in one transaction. If one of them fails then both should be rolled back. I took @BillWeiner advice and can pass the same id to my inserts but still am unable to do a begin/commit transaction block for redshift.It complains that you cannot do commit if auto_commit is ON but then there’s no way to set it to OFF. From reading online it might again be a bug

Comment: OK now I'm seeing the issue.  What bench are you using to connect to Redshift?  Autocommit is a property of the connection to Redshift so it is likely that changing this setting will mean knowing how to in your bench.

Comment: @BillWeiner I am using DataGrip IDE for adhoc querying and it does not seem to have that option. More importantly I am connecting through python using psycopg2. Any way to provide this property using it? My understanding from looking online is that you just cannot change this property in redshift anymore.

Comment: I've never used DataGrip but I do see with a quick google search others having issues with transactions and turning off autocommit.  Others may be able to help with this.  As for psycopg2 I believe it has autocommit off by default but the connection behavior is controllable.  If you do "conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=..." then you can set autocommit by "conn.autocommit = True" or "conn.autocommit = False" in your code.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look into the psycopg2 option